# How to resolve NG0100 in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular app I have the following component:

**html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="list$ | async as list">
  <mat-card-content class="deep-flex">
    <mat-list class="categories-list">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let category of list">
        <mat-icon class="primary-bg"> check </mat-icon>
        {{ category }}
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-card-content>
</ng-container>
```

**ts**

```
user$ = this.userService.user$;
private reformatList = new Subject<MatchFormatter>();
type MatchFormatter = (arr: string[]) => string[];

list$: Observable<string[]> = this.reformatList.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.user$),
  map(([callback, user]: [MatchFormatter, User]) =>
    callback(
      Object.entries(user.match).reduce(
        (acc: string[], [key, value]: [string, any]) => {
          const excludedKeys = ['score', 'match'];
          if (excludedKeys.includes(key)) return acc;
            value > 0 ? acc.push(key) : acc;
          return acc;
        },
        [],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  startWith([]),
);

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const callback = (res: string[]) => res;
  this.reformatList.next(cb);
}
```

With this code the app will work, but I get a `NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked` error because I'm modifing the view after it has been checked.
The problem is that I need to use `ngAfterViewInit` to initialize `matchingList$`, since if I do it with `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterContentInit` I won't be able to see any category in `list`.

I think that possible solutions might include:

- Force change detection after the modification of `matchingList$` (e.g. `detectChanges()`).
- Transform `reformatList` in a `BehaviourSubject` and moving my logic from `AfterViewInit` to `OnInit`.

Is there any better solution? I want to avoid forcing change detection, so I could stick with the second one, but I feel that `BehaviourSubject` is not the best way to go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue simply by moving the `startWith` inside the pipe:

```
list$: Observable<string[]> = this.reformatList.pipe(
  startWith((list) => list.slice(0, 3)),
  withLatestFrom(this.user$),
  map(([callback, user]: [MatchFormatter, User]) =>
    callback(
      Object.entries(user.match).reduce(
        (acc: string[], [key, value]: [string, any]) => {
          const excludedKeys = ['score', 'match'];
          if (excludedKeys.includes(key)) return acc;
            value > 0 ? acc.push(key) : acc;
          return acc;
        },
        [],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The answer of @Mathias Ravelojaona works, but writing the pipe with the instructions on how to build the stream directly when declaring the stream seems more declarative and clearer, so I preferred to avoid `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1):

you can use ngOnInit and move the initialization logic to ngOnInit so you are in sync with your subject

```js
user$ = this.userService.user$;
private reformatList = new Subject<MatchFormatter>();
type MatchFormatter = (arr: string[]) => string[];

list$!: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  const callback = (res: string[]) => res;
  this.list$ = this.reformatList.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.user$),
  map(([callback, user]: [MatchFormatter, User]) =>
    callback(
      Object.entries(user.match).reduce(
        (acc: string[], [key, value]: [string, any]) => {
          const excludedKeys = ['score', 'match'];
          if (excludedKeys.includes(key)) return acc;
            value > 0 ? acc.push(key) : acc;
          return acc;
        },
        [],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  startWith([]),
);
  this.reformatList.next(cb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I solved the issue by moving the `startWith` at the beginning of the pipe, in this way `ngOnInit` is not required and the code is more declarative.